# Dell D6000 thunderbolt hub and macbook pro 2018

Tags: macbook-pro, display, sleep-wake, dock, thunderbolt

I have the a [dell thunderbolt hub D6000](https://www.dell.com/en-uk/work/shop/dell-universal-dock-d6000/apd/452-bcyj/pc-accessories) which is connected to two displays via DisplayPort and the hub is connected into my Macbook pro 15” 2018. I have the latest DisplayLink driver installed (5.0.1). I use my laptop in clam shell mode i.e. the lid is closed.

The issue is when I want to disconnect the laptop and use its built in screen when I open the lid the screen remains completely black and nothing seems to fix it until I restart.

Things I have tried:

- Opening the display settings and finding with them
- Toggle “Automatic Graphics Switching”
- Close and open the lid a bunch of times
- Leave the lid opened for a long time
- Quitting all of my apps

Anyone else having the same issue?

Comment: According to the DisplayLink macOS software download page at https://www.displaylink.com/downloads/macos, version 5.2.15 (a18c374) was released on 27th June 2019 with a number of fixes related to blank or frozen displays. I recommend downloading this version and giving it at try.